# Get flow name in Invocable Method

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, invocablevariable

is it possible to get a flow name that invoked the invocable method in Apex?

Basically, I want to implement the getFlowName method that dynamically returns a flow name that invoked this method.

```java
@InvocableMethod
global static void myMethod(List<InvocableLog> logs) {
    String flowName = getFlowName();
}
```

I looked into the `Flow.Interview` class and didn't find anything.
**Setting an invocable variable won't be accepted.**

I guess it's not possible, so asking for confirmation or any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The only data that's passed in is whatever you set in your invocablevariable properties.